# Run multiple protractor scripts in one action?

Tags: protractor

I have my protractor scripts running. But on my current scenario, to run the tests it is needed to run each .js individually. I want to pack all the test files into one or pack all the test files into an executable (what it would be ideal because it won't be needed to have protractor installed on all the machines running the tests.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Why is it needed to run each individually ?

Comment: Please add how you start your protractor server, do you do `protractor conf.js` and leave it running while running tests via another window/session ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust config to run all your tests:

For instance if you have `todo-spec.js` and `todo-new-spec.js` you can run both of them with:

```
exports.config = { 
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['*-spec.js']
};
```

As for running protractor without having protractor, not sure about that.

Example that I tried to show this:

[image]

Comment: I put specs:['*spec.js'], as you suggested and then I got: W/configParser - pattern *spec.js did not match any files. Is this syntax correct?

Comment: It worked for me - screenshot added.  Please go through code slowly and look for a typo somewhere.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't add the screenshot of my config file and the result I got. So I will explain what I did. All my test files ends in .js, so I put specs['*js']. I replaced directConnect:true to seleniumAdress:"http://localhost:4444'wd'hub". But then I got: No spes found.

Comment: Please consider upvoting if this information is useful.  I suggest you start a brand new project and get two examples tests running - this would duplicate what I did in 5 minutes above today.  Then you can compare and contrast to see where the issue is.

Comment: I took advantage of your suggestion. Instead of use  specs: ['*-spec.js'], I put specs: ['../tests/726_BackFlowNAV.js', and all the specs I have].This worked perfectly. Thank you for your supporting.

Comment: Ah directory `tests`.  Maybe `['./tests/*spec.js']` would work

Comment: @IngriddBrito is your spec files under the same directory as config file , else you have to provide full path or /**/*js

Comment: Look to use blahblah.test.js or blahblah.spec.js for your filenames and then you'll be able to wildcard them appropriately.  I suggest using originalFileName.test.js and keeping it in the *same* directory.  This is a personal recommendation. i like to see the test *right next* to the code.  Another directory starts to push it apart.  Others will disagree with this.

Comment: +1 to PDHide for the ``**`` option. More at https://stackoverflow.com/a/28199633/631619

Comment: I have 2 directories: config and tests. I also tried ['./tests/*spec.js'] and I ran calling:  protractor .\config\confall.js where confall has specs ['./tests/*spec.js']. But I got:   pattern ./tests/*spec.js did not match any files.

Comment: @IngriddBrito you don't need the dot  I guess

Answer (score 1):

#### We may organise tests in the form of suites(inside conf.js):

For instance, you may have suites for different types of functionality of your application, homepage, search etc:

```
suites: {
  homepage: 'tests/e2e/homepage/**/*Spec.js',
  search: [
    'tests/e2e/contact_search/**/*Spec.js',
    'tests/e2e/venue_search/**/*Spec.js'
  ] 
},
```

And/or, you may have specs grouped into suites by the type of tests:

```
suites: {
  smoke: 'tests/e2e/smoke/*.js',
  performance: 'tests/e2e/performance/*.js'
},
```

and execute them something like:

```
$ protractor conf.js --suite smoke
```